# Why is multiple Application.VLookup into array dreadfully slow?

Tags: excel, vba, performance

I have an external workbook from which I need to get data into my main workbook.
In the past i did this using A LOT of vlookups - and as a result the calculation was extremely slow. In order to speed things up, I have tried to convert the data from the external workbook into an array(arr2), and then doing the lookups into this. The result is that it's even more slow now..

The lookup value is composed of the values from two cells. I roughly have 1000 rows which, the way i do it, needs to be looped through in 44 columns. While it is actually working on a limited amount of rows, after one hour it is still processing when listing all 1000 rows.

What can be done to speed things up?

```
Dim arr1() As Variant, arr2() As Variant, arr3() As Variant
Dim sup1 As Long, sup2 As Long, sup3 As Long, sup4 As Long, sup5 As Long, sup6 As Long, sup7 As Long, 
sup8 As Long, sup9 As Long, sup10 As Long, sup11 As Long, sup12 As Long, sup13 As Long, sup14 As 
Long, sup15 As Long
Dim i As Long, WS1 As Worksheet
    
Dim Book1 As Workbook, book2 As Workbook

Dim book2Name As String
book2Name = "SupportTables.xlsx"

Dim book2NamePath As String
book2NamePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & book2Name

Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Sheets("sheet1").Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set Book1 = ThisWorkbook

If IsOpen(book2Name) = False Then Workbooks.Open (book2NamePath)

Set book2 = Workbooks(book2Name)
Set WS1 = book2.Worksheets("pricediscinfo")

sup1 = Range("AN12")
sup2 = Range("AQ12")
...
sup15 = Range("CD12")

    arr1 = Range("T15:T" & lastrow)
    ReDim arr3(1 To UBound(arr1), 1 To 44)

arr2 = WS1.Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Value

For i = 1 To UBound(arr1)

arr3(i, 1) = Application.VLookup(arr1(i, 1) & sup1, arr2, 12, False)
arr3(i, 2) = Application.VLookup(arr1(i, 1) & sup1, arr2, 9, False)
...
arr3(i, 43) = Application.VLookup(arr1(i, 1) & sup15, arr2, 12, False)
arr3(i, 44) = Application.VLookup(arr1(i, 1) & sup15, arr2, 9, False)

Next i

Range("AN15:CE" & lastrow).Value = arr3
```

Any input appriciated!

Comment: I think should be `arr2` should be a `range`, so `set arr2 = WS1.Range("a1").CurrentRegion` the range maybe?

Comment: PowerQuery might be faster.

Comment: You should consider loading the lookup range (the range against which you'd normally do the VLOOKUP) into a dictionary object. Lookups into a dictionary are constant time, and 44k lookups should finish more quickly. If you have trouble finding information, write back and we can try to help.

Comment: When ever you feel you need to number your variables `sup1`…`sup15` you're doing it wrong and should use arrays instead: `Dim sup(1 To 15) As Long` and you get rid of 14 clunky `dim` statements.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Pᴇʜ! I'll clean it up right away.
@basodre Do you mind helping me a bit? Dictionaries is something new to me.

Comment: @JBKrarup just how you could rewrite that code for better readabiliy. Use meaninful variable names and declare variables as close as possible to their first use. See [here](https://gist.github.com/pcr-coding/62e3ab997879c69707f9ddc005ea95f5). Also make sure you specify for all ranges in which workbook and worksheet they are.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, Thanks!! I see what you mean, it really tighten things up - For sure something I need to pay more attention to in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionaries are just a collection of key, value pairs like an 1 dimension array but with a string allowed as the key rather than just numbers. In this case because you want to look up 2 columns, the value that a key refers to I chose to be a 2 element array. For more complex cases you might just store the row number as the dictionary value and use it to get the value of any column on the lookup sheet (or array). See [Dictionary Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object)

Update : `(ws2.Cells(1, "I")` corrected to `(ws2.Cells(i, "I")`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FasterLookUp()

    Const WB2_NAME = "SupportTables.xlsx"
    Const WS2_NAME = "pricediscinfo"
    
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim iLastrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim arr1, arr2, arr3, sPath As String, s As String
    Dim isOpen As Boolean, t0 As Single

    Dim dict As Object, k
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
    sPath = wb1.Path & "\"
 
    ' configuration
    Dim sup(15) As String, supCol
    supCol = Array("AN", "AQ", "AR", "AS", "AT", _
                   "AU", "AV", "AW", "AX", "AY", _
                   "AZ", "BA", "BB", "BC", "CD")
    For i = 1 To 15
        sup(i) = ws1.Cells(12, supCol(i - 1))
        s = s & "sup(" & i & ") = " & sup(i) & vbCr
    Next
    MsgBox s ' for checking code
    
    ' open workbook if not already open
    isOpen = False
    For Each wb2 In Application.Workbooks
        If wb2.Name = WB2_NAME Then
            isOpen = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If isOpen = False Then
        Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(sPath & "\" & WB2_NAME, True, True) ' update links, read only
    End If

    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets(WS2_NAME)
    iLastrow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' build dictionary as lookup table
    t0 = Timer
    For i = 1 To iLastrow
        k = Trim(ws2.Cells(i, "A")) ' key
        If Len(k) > 0 Then
            If dict.exists(k) Then
                MsgBox "Duplicate key " & k, vbCritical, "Row " & i
                Exit Sub
            Else
                ' col I and col L
                dict.Add k, Array(ws2.Cells(i, "I"), ws2.Cells(i, "L")) ' lookups
            End If
       End If
    Next
    MsgBox dict.Count & " Items scanned into dictionary from " & ws2.Name, _
           vbInformation, "Took " & Int(Timer - t0) & " seconds"

    ' update this workbook
    t0 = Timer
    iLastrow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Row
    arr1 = ws1.Range("T15:T" & iLastrow)
    ReDim arr3(UBound(arr1), 1 To 44)
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr1)
        s = arr1(i, 1)
        k = s & sup(1)
        If dict.exists(k) Then
            arr3(i, 1) = dict(k)(1) ' col L
            arr3(i, 2) = dict(k)(0) ' col I
        Else
           'Debug.Print "No match '" & k & "'"
        End If
        ''
        k = s & sup(15)
        If dict.exists(k) Then
            arr3(i, 1) = dict(k)(1) ' col L
            arr3(i, 2) = dict(k)(0) ' col I
        Else
            'Debug.Print "No match '" & k & "'"
        End If
    Next i

    If isOpen = False Then wb2.Close False ' close if opened
    ws1.Range("AN15:CE" & iLastrow).Value = arr3
    MsgBox "Udate done", vbInformation, "Took " & Int(Timer - t0) & " seconds"
End Sub
```